# faster geometric average on ASCII

Tags: python

Is it possible to speed up the following code, but without using external modules (NumPy, etc)? Just plain Python. Two lines of thought: speeding the computation in

```
chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen), 0) ) )
```

or faster building of the desired structure. The aim is to find the geometric average of an ord() of an ASCII symbol and report it as a round value (symbol). The len(InDict) is anything above 1. The outcome of the example should be

```
KM<I
```

The code:

```
def GA():
    InStr="0204507890"
    InDict={
       0:"ABCDEFGHIJ",
       1:"KLMNOPQRST",
       2:"WXYZ#&/()?"
       }

    OutStr = ""

    DLen = len(InDict)
    for pos in zip(InStr, *InDict.values()):
        if pos[0]=="0":
            multiplOrds = 1
            for mul in (ord(char) for char in pos[1:] if char!="!"): multiplOrds*=mul
            OutStr+= chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen), 0) ) )

    return OutStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("GA()", setup="from __main__ import GA"))
```

Comment: How long is this taking for you? and what is your goal? Is this code bottle-necking something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using python3.

Here is the fastest code I could get with provided information, `GA_old` is old function `GA` is optimized function. I moved input initialization to the global scope since it's not interesting to optimize initialization and I assume you get your input from other place and don't use the same input all the time.

So here is the code:

```
InStr="0204507890"
InDict={
   0:"ABCDEFGHIJ",
   1:"KLMNOPQRST",
   2:"WXYZ#&/()?"
}

def GA():
    OutStr = ""

    p = 1.0 / len(InDict)
    for pos,rest in zip(InStr, zip(*InDict.values())):
        if pos == "0":
            product = 1
            for char in rest:
                if char != '!':
                    product*= ord(char)
            OutStr += chr(int(round(product ** p)))
    return OutStr

def GA_old():

    OutStr = ""

    DLen = len(InDict)
    for pos in zip(InStr, *InDict.values()):
        if pos[0]=="0":
            multiplOrds = 1
            for mul in (ord(char) for char in pos[1:] if char!="!"): multiplOrds*=mul
            OutStr+= chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen), 0) ) )
    return OutStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert GA_old() == GA()
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("GA()", setup="from __main__ import GA", number=100000))
    print(timeit.timeit("GA_old()", setup="from __main__ import GA_old", number=100000))
```

it produces following output on my machine (`python 3.4.3`):

```
 ⚡ python3 t.py 
0.6274565359999542
1.1968618339960813
```

Most of the speedup I got from following:

- don't use list comprehension here `for mul in (ord(char) for char in pos[1:] if char!="!"):`. Looks like python creates 2-level iterator and this is quite slower. Also embedding this comprehension into single loop with `if` improves readability IMO.
- (*very surprisingly*) removing second argument of `round` function speeds up function quite significantly. I can't explain this, it looks like minor performance bug in python.

But I think it could be optimized even more, but it will require knowledge about your real data (I guess you don't optimize this particular case that completes in fraction of second).

Some ideas:

- if your strings are long try not to append to them but use advise from other answers  (`bytearray` or `"".join(...)`)
- try to use cache for `chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen))))` (put already computed results to global dict and don't recompute value if it can be found in the dict).
- instead of calculating `multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen)` you can try to precompute table of `ord(c) ** DLen` for each possible character and try to search `multiplOrds` in this precomputed table.

None of this ideas will work good on input data that you posted since it's  very small, but it may work good on bigger inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much! "1.0 / len(InDict)" in every append was quite stupid indeed. I am surprised by the round behaviour, since providing a default usually speeds the function. Interesting idea of splitting the first zip in two parts. Yes, I do use bytearrays in this and the rest of the program, this code was just an illustration. I can have precomputed ord() in a list or dict, but that is as far as it will go. InDict can contain many keys and 1000s of chars in each value. All possible combinations are too many for a precomputed structure. BTW in another part of the code I use such strategy.

Answer (score 6):

A first thought:

Concatenating strings is slow as they are immutable, therefore each modification results in creating a new copied instance. That's why you should not do things like:

```
s = ""
for i in range(1000000):
    s += chr(65)
```

Each loop it will create a new string instance being one character larger than the previous, the old instance will remain until the Garbage Collector kicks in. Also allocating memory is slow.

Using a generator expression to store the partial strings and joining them together in the end is about twice as fast and shorter to code:

```
s = "".join(chr(65) for i in range(1000000))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid point. I am actually aware of it, but my conundrum is if the rest of the math or the walk could be improved. Here, I did string re-creation for the sake of simplicity of the example. Anyhow, point taken.

Comment: A list comp is also faster than a generator

Comment: I do not want to create new list in memory. This is part of multiprocess code, which is already bulky in a sense.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to make a wild guess, so you can run your code under the profilers, especially line-by-line profiler: https://zapier.com/engineering/profiling-python-boss/

Also, when you need to store and concatenate a list of ASCII characters, it worst to look into using of `bytearray` instead of `list` or `string` for storing `OutStr`.

I noticed my changes in your code with comments:

```
def GA():
    InStr="0204507890"
    InDict={
       0:"ABCDEFGHIJ",
       1:"KLMNOPQRST",
       2:"WXYZ#&/()?"
    }
    OutStr = bytearray() # use bytearray instead of string

    DLen = len(InDict)
    for pos in zip(InStr, *InDict.values()):
        if pos[0]=="0":
            multiplOrds = 1
            for mul in (ord(char) for char in pos[1:] if char!="!"):     multiplOrds*=mul
            OutStr+= chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen), 0) ) )

    return str(OutStr) # convert bytearray to string
```

Link to very interesting talk regarding usage of `bytearray`:

http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/ (Oh, Come On. Who Needs Bytearrays?)

Comment: If the OP seriously wants to improve performance, profiling is a must.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use a lookup table or big switch statement with precalculated values? I'm not a python person, but this looks very messy. :)

Also I don't get what it is actually doing, so a few real examples (input->output) might help people to help you better, maybe even redisigning your whole algorithm, not only optimizing parts.

I tried on python fiddle: Is InDict always the same? Can the InStr be longer than InDict? Why do you only calculate something for 0-values?

Basically you seem to reduce every column of InDict to these numbers and then pick the one where the InStr is zero:

```
var ia = [ 75, 76, 77, 78, 58, 60, 65, 62, 63, 73 ]

var sa = [ "K", "L", "M", "N", ":", "<", "A", ">", "?", "I" ]
```

None of this makes sense to me, so i'm out for now, will check once you supply more information. Also, for what purpose are you writing the code?

And the fiddle thing gives me KM, not KM<I for your example? The < is fine, but it seems to break when the I is appended.

Another two ideas:

I think x**(1/n) is the n-th root of x, maybe there are faster functions for that if n is small.

Also since you are rounding the value anyway, you could replace it by a Taylor-sum and stop calculating as soon as the result is close enough.

And you could create thresholds for all the values, so you only have to go through the list and find the right value. So you just iterate once from 0 to maxX and calculate (x+0.5)**n, should be faster. Maybe do a check, how many values below/above are included and adjust the thresholds.

Comment: This is not an answer. Use comments instead. If you can't comment, get more points(10 if I remember correctly).

Comment: I'm not sure if an answer or rather advice.

Comment: Well the answer is to precalculate, which only makes sense if InStr is a lot longer or the function gets called a lot and InDict is always the same, hence the question.

Comment: I think this is good enough as an answer from a new member +1

Comment: Thank you for these comments. InDict is not the same, indeed it is different for every function call. It has at least 1 key, but possibly up till 9, each containing 300 to 4000 characters in a value. InStr and InDict are always size matched, but are different for each call. pos=="0" is just a condition for that example, but can be every ASCII you want from the function.

Comment: Then you are pretty much doomed to calculate it real time. Or use a fast database (redis, mongo, ..) to store the values outside of your script. Also if python is just interpreting slow, you can try to move those calculations to an external compiled program in C or Swift.

Comment: Is there any name for what you are doing, something like "middle-out compression"? Might help the next person that is searching for it .. and I am curious what you are actually doing! :)

Comment: also, try looking if CUDA helps you, this stuff seems like it might benefit from multiple pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the same implementation as dim-am, but I don't appear to be able to make comments yet. To make speedups more clearly, I added a bit more to the timing code. A drift of +/- 0.5% seems to occur, but so far I can't find a way to make it faster.

```
InStr="0204507890"
InDict={
   0:"ABCDEFGHIJ",
   1:"KLMNOPQRST",
   2:"WXYZ#&/()?"
}

def GA1():
    OutStr = ""

    p = 1.0 / len(InDict)
    for pos,rest in zip(InStr, zip(*InDict.values())):
        if pos == "0":
            product = 1
            for char in rest:
                if char != '!':
                    product*= ord(char)
            OutStr += chr(int(round(product ** p)))
    return OutStr

def GA():
    """Mess around with this one."""
    OutStr = ""

    p = 1.0 / len(InDict)
    for pos,rest in zip(InStr, zip(*InDict.values())):
        if pos == "0":
            product = 1
            for char in rest:
                if char != '!':
                    product*= ord(char)
            OutStr += chr(int(round(product ** p)))
    return OutStr


def GA_old():

    OutStr = ""

    DLen = len(InDict)
    for pos in zip(InStr, *InDict.values()):
        if pos[0]=="0":
            multiplOrds = 1
            for mul in (ord(char) for char in pos[1:] if char!="!"):     multiplOrds*=mul
            OutStr+= chr(int(round( multiplOrds**(1.0/DLen), 0) ) )
    return OutStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Ensuring equivalent functionality...")
    assert GA_old() == GA()
    assert GA_old() == GA1()
    print("OK.")
    print("Running timed test of alternative implementations, please wait...")
    import timeit
    tNew = (timeit.timeit("GA()", setup="from __main__ import GA", number=100000))
    tRef = (timeit.timeit("GA1()", setup="from __main__ import GA1", number=100000))
    tOld = (timeit.timeit("GA_old()", setup="from __main__ import GA_old", number=100000))
    percent_speedup = 100 * (1.0 - (tNew / tOld))
    percent_speedup_ref = 100 * (1.0 - (tRef / tOld))
    percent_relative = 100 * ( 1.0 - (tNew/tRef))
    print("Base time: {0}, New time: {1}, Speedup (%): {2}".format(tOld,tNew, percent_speedup) )
    print("Ref time: {0}, Ref Speedup (%): {1}, \nSpeedup relative to reference(%): {2}".format(tRef, percent_speedup_ref, percent_relative) )
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll weigh in, though no code sample.

You are trying to compute the product of a exponential.  Instead compute the logarithm.